# An example about "rectract" but not "homotopy equivalence"

Tags: algebraic-topology

Can you help me to find an example for a pair $(X,A)$ such that $A$ is a retract of $X$, but $A$ and $X$ is not homotopy equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

Let $(X,A)=(S^1,s)$ where $s$ is a point of $S^1$. They are not homotopy equivalent, i.e. the sphere is not contractible. You could also take $A=\{(x,y)\in S^1 \mid y\ge0\}$

Comment: I guess this goes to show that the sphere is a very simple and useful object to keep in mind when looking for examples!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe $X = S^1$ and $A$ = a point?